# JavaFX: ColorPicker returns the same value every time

Tags: java, javafx, color-picker

So I'm trying to fill my Rectangle with Color Picker, but it doesn't cooperate. 
I do it like this:

```
@FXML
private ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(Color.BLACK);
```

```
    @FXML
    public void changeColor()
    {    
        myRect.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());
        System.out.println("color = " + colorPicker.getValue());
    }
```

I binded this function to the ColorPicker in SceneBuilder, but when I choose a color, my rectangle only changes its color to black (or whatever default color I put in constructor) independently of what color I choose. So every time I pick a color I get the output "color = 0xff0000ff". Is it because I'm not using EventHandler (I somehow couldn't get it to work in the initialize function)? In my understanding if I bind it this function to the OnAction field it should work exactly like a Listener.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

             window = primaryStage;
             Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MainScreen.fxml"));

             Scene scene = new Scene(root);
             window.setScene(scene);
             window.show();




        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
public class Controller{
    @FXML
    private  ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(Color.BLACK);

    @FXML
    private Rectangle myRect;

    public void initialize(){}

    @FXML
    public void changeWaveColor()
    {    
        myRect.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());
        System.out.println("Function color = " + colorPicker.getValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not initialize fields that are supposed to be injected. If you use proper code, the instance the field is initialized with is simply dropped. If you do not use proper code, this may cover up an issue with injecting the node; in this case you're better off immediately recognizing there is an error instead of having to find out when an issue like this shows up... (Please show the element corresponding to the `ColorPicker` in the fxml. I'm pretty sure this is the source of your issue.)

Comment: @fabian are you talking about this line? ```@FXML
    private  ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(Color.BLACK);```  I did it in fxml like this:  <ColorPicker fx:id="waveColor" onAction="#changeWaveColor" />

Comment: Indeed and there is your error: `fx:id="waveColor"`. The value of `fx:id` needs to match the field name in the controller (-> Either `fx:id="colorPicker"` or `@FXML private ColorPicker waveColor;`).

Comment: Omg thank you so much. Such a silly mistake...